# How to let Lua see the contents of a variable rather than just the variable name in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, lua

I have some Lua code which searches for "①" and "②" within some text and prints only the text displayed between:

```
\startluacode
    userdata = userdata or {}

    function userdata.printbetween(str, m1, m2)
        m1 = m1 or "①"
        m2 = m2 or "②"
        mat_pat = string.format('%s(.*)%s', m1, m2)
        str = string.match(str, mat_pat) or str
        context(str)
    end
\stopluacode

\define\sentence{This is ① a final ② test sentence.}

\define[1]\textbetween{%
    \ctxlua{userdata.printbetween([===[#1]===])}%
}

\starttext
    \startitemize[n]
        \item \textbetween{This is ① a test ② sentence.}
        \item \textbetween{This is ① another test ② sentence.}
        \item \textbetween{\sentence}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

This should print:

```
1. a test
2. another test
3. a final
```

Instead, this is printing:

```
1. a test
2. another test
3. This is ① a final ② test sentence.
```

When I give Lua a variable, such as `\sentence`, it appears to process "\sentence" and not the data contained inside `\sentence`.

How can I let Lua examine the contents inside the variable rather than just examining the variable's name?

Comment: `\define` makes the definition unexpandable. Try `\def\sentence{....}` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\define` makes the definition unexpandable. Instead use

```
\def\sentence{....}
```